# Unity3D - Failed to re-package resources | Android APK

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, compilation, apk, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to compile a simple game without any additional plugin, but I am facing the errors below:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String[] progress_strings, Single progress_value, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.CompileResources (System.String stagingArea, System.String packageName, UnityEditor.Android.AndroidLibraries androidLibraries)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcessInternal (System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()


Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]
```

I have the latest versions of the Android SDK and JDK (Image updated after  Answer of @Programmer):

[image]

I do not include any plugin or Google service, what might be happening?

***UnityVersion: 5.3.4f1 Personal***

On **Unity 5.4.0b15**, We have another error:

```
UnityException: Build failure
Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuildPointToConsole (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:176)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be the spaces in the Android SDK and NDK path. Unity's update logs always says that this problem is fixed but that is not true. It fails sometimes.

1. Make sure that there are **no** spaces in your SDK and NDK path. So create a folder called `AndroidSDK` and `AndroidNDK` in the C directory.
2. Copy your `Android-sdk` folder to the `C:/AndroidSDK` directory. Copy your `Android-ndk` to the  `C:/AndroidNDK folder`.

Now, your SDK path should look like this:

```
C:/AndroidSDK/Android-sdk
C:/AndroidNDK/Android-ndk
```

No spaces more.

3. Update your Android SDK and NDK paths in the Unity Editor.

If that fails, download [Unity 5.4 beta](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta).

**EDIT**:

Re-download [SDK](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip). Then Build the Project for Android, it will show an **error** and ask you to update SDK. click on the "**Update Android SDK**" buttom. Unity will Automatically update your SDK. Your SDK should then look like something below.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Programmer thanks for your reply, but, this not works for me! I'am downloading the latest version of Unity (beta).

Comment: download the latest beta and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: @Programmer I give the new error! The question has been updated!

Comment: @IgoR create an empty **new** project and run it on your Android.

Comment: @Programmer get same error :\ I can't compile the apk file

Comment: @IgoR Forgot to ask. Windows or Mac?

Comment: @Programmer Windows 10 PRO 64bits

Comment: @IgoR Delete the current Android SDK  you have. Download from here http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip Try again and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110320/discussion-between-igor-and-programmer).