# Unity3D - Failed to re-package resources | Android APK - No Answer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I already find my problem here but I can't ask for help. My problem is same as here: [Unity3D - Failed to re-package resources | Android APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854489/unity3d-failed-to-re-package-resources-android-apk) and I tried everything, I downloaded new SDK from link, removed spaces but still nothing.

Please Help,
best regards,
Sasa Grujic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem, for myself at least.

First I tried to remove unity and android sdk and install everything again, but it didn't work. Then, after some time not using it, I erased everything that has any bound to unity or android sdk and install it again. After that (this is what, I think, solved the problem) I went to Windows device manager and found my phone and updated driver automatically.

I hope this will help someone with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you. I tried everything and ultimately I rollback to an older saved version of my project.

My advice is to check all plugins and sdk you are using because you may be using an older/newer version and is causing you problems.

Anyway, can you paste the console log? the full message. I may be able to help you.

Regards.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying,
There is nothing in console error or stderr log, it's empty.
Also, I don't use any plugins, I've tried new project and the error is same.

Here it is:  

Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
C:\Android\androidSdk\build-tools\24.0.0-preview\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Android/androidSdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[

]
stdout[

]

I moved project to other computer and it worked.